# How to configure AnyEvent::DNS resolver by default?

Tags: perl, asynchronous, dns, anyevent

How to configure `AnyEvent::DNS` resolver by default, I want to change `max_outstanding`, `reuse`, `timeout`.
There is an environment variable `$ENV{PERL_ANYEVENT_MAX_OUTSTANDING_DNS}`, but how to change `reuse` and `timeout` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ENV{PERL_ANYEVENT_MAX_OUTSTANDING_DNS}` is only used if the default resolver is used, so you must be using the default resolver, so you can just change the default resolver.

```
use AnyEvent::DNS qw( );

my $resolver = AnyEvent::DNS->new(
   untaint         => 1,
   max_outstanding => $ENV{PERL_ANYEVENT_MAX_OUTSTANDING_DNS}*1 || ...,
   reuse           => ...,
   timeout         => ...,
);

$ENV{PERL_ANYEVENT_RESOLV_CONF}
   ? $resolver->_load_resolv_conf_file($ENV{PERL_ANYEVENT_RESOLV_CONF})
   : $resolver->os_config;

$AnyEvent::DNS::RESOLVER = $resolver;
```

Comment: Once again I say thank you. I do not quite understand what defines reuse in the settings of the AnyEvent::DNS. The description says: "The number of seconds (default: 300) that a query id cannot be re-used after a timeout. If there was no time-out then query ids can be reused immediately." What is a "query id" and why does it wait for 300 seconds?

Comment: Don't know. . .